# Drosophila melanogaster eclosion

Tags: development, experimental-design, drosophila

Is there any published data which shows the number of *Drosophila melanogaster* fruit flies eclosing (hatching out of the pupae) against time since egg oviposition? I'm thinking there should be something like a "cumulative flies eclosed" plot showing the cumulative number of flies emerging per time interval after the eggs were oviposited (something like this dummy figure).

[image]

I expected to find this in the Ashburner et al *Drosophila* book but there was nothing. I am trying to see how much variance there is around the mean for an experiment design. It may be helpful to know (though I am not necessarily after specifics to this set up) we keep our flies at 25 degrees, 12:12 light dark cycle, 60% humidty on a yeast and sugar based food source. The flies are an African lab adapted population (Dahomey ca ~1970's?) and eggs in the experiment would be kept at low density so resource competition is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although I found [this study](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01989734), where mean and 95% CIs of median time to
eclosion (h) are provided for some strains of D.m. (with a resolution of 12 h) (in table 3), the moment of eclosion seems to be under [circadian control](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8695895): "in Drosophila melanogaster, the emergence of adults from their pupal cases (eclosion) is gated by the circadian clock such that it occurs during a window of approximately 8-10 h starting 1-2 h before lights-on in 12-h light:12-h dark cycles (LD)". In that particular study Canton-S flies eclosed within 4-5 days after pupation (LD 12:12, 25°C) with the following distribution over day (digitized from Fig. 1A [numbers are approximate, percents don't sum up to 100]):

```
Hours   % eclosed
Dark
12-14   0.5
14-16   0.4
16-18   0.6
18-20   1.1
20-22   1.4
22-24   5.6

Light
0-1     20.4
1-2     9.3
2-3     13.7
3-4     12.0
4-5     10.3
5-6     11.3
6-7     6.6
7-8     4.9
8-9     2.1
9-10    0.8
10-11   0.8
11-12   0.4
```